# How to convert string field into integer field in ELK?

Tags: elk

I am trying to convert one of our field which is in String to Integer. I tried all methods to convert but all methods are failed.

I tried in Kibana using painless, Logstash using mutate filter and Elasticsearch using reindex API.

This is our logs:

> Sep 13 10:37:01 SYSTROMEGGN APP_TRAFFIC:
>   SerialNum=H000D-8D31U-2000P-H0H5Q-E028T GenTime="2019-09-13 10:37:01"
>   StartTime="2019-09-13 10:36:00" EndTime="2019-09-13 10:37:00"
>   Category="search-engine" AppName="truecaller" Traffic=31104

All field types are by default string but I want "Traffic" field in integer.
This is my logstash configuration pipeline:

```
input {
     udp {
       port => 5044
       type => "syslog"
     }
}

filter{
      if [type] == "syslog" {
          grok {
            match => { "message" => "% . 
               {SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{WORD:syslog_type}% 
               {DATA:syslog_program}:%{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" 
            }
          }
          date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
          }
          kv {
            source => "syslog_message"
            value_split => "="
          }
      }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["http://192.168.0.62:9200"]
      index => "syslog"
      document_type => "system_logs"
      user=>"elastic"
      password=>"elastic"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I expect the output is that my "Traffic" field converted in Integer type but the actual output is "Traffic" field in String type.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a mutate section inside filter in your logstash config. This should work, please share your config with mutate section to see why it is not working.

```
  filter{
       -----
       mutate {
           convert => { "your_field_name" => "integer" }
       }

   }
```

Comment: Check your datatype for the field in Kibana Index Management? Also check if your data is always a number, you may be getting null or some other characters then that could be an issue.

Comment: My datatype for the field is string in kibana index management and data or value is always a number.

Comment: I assume elasticsearch is storing this as String since your mapping is string. Why cant you change the mapping in Elasticsearch to number and see? Also if the datatype is number then you dont need any mutate, Elasticsearch will store it as number

Comment: I change the mapping in elasticsearch  but there is an error.Can you please tell me that how could I change the mapping in elasticsearch to number.

Comment: You should probably share your property mapping to see what is the issue you are facing. You can find examples of property mapping here, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: PUT /syslog/_mapping

{
  
   "mapping": {
    
   "properties": {
      "Traffic": {
       
        "type": "integer",
  
        "fields": {
         
        "keyword": {

        "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
         
        }
        
       }
             
      }
     }
    }
   }

Comment: This should be a simple structure like this, { "mapping": 
    { 
        "properties": 
        { 
            "Traffic": { "type": "integer" },
            "any_other_field":{ "type": "keyword" }
        }
    }
} . You are making traffic as a complex structure like traffic.keyword which is not working here

Comment: There is an error like-Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters.